# ImportError: cannot import name create_urllib3_context

Tags: python, google-api, urllib3

I'm working on a script that use google API, with reference at the following tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#InsertDataOption

the script works fine in the windows PC with python 3.6, while i've some problem if i run the same script in raspbian with python 3.4.
the script rises the following error:

```
    from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow,Flow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .interactive import get_user_credentials
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/interactive.py", line 24, in <module>
    import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 67, in <module>
    import google.auth.transport.requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 39, in <module>
    from requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_ import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_urllib3_context'
```

I've also checkd the pip3 list for the installed libraries:

```
cachetools (4.1.1)
certifi (2020.6.20)
chardet (2.3.0)
codebug-i2c-tether (0.2.3)
codebug-tether (0.7.0)
colorama (0.3.2)
emoji (0.5.4)
Flask (0.10.1)
google-api-core (1.22.2)
google-api-python-client (1.11.0)
google-auth (1.21.1)
google-auth-httplib2 (0.0.4)
google-auth-oauthlib (0.4.1)
googleapis-common-protos (1.52.0)
gpiozero (1.3.1)
html5lib (0.999)
httplib2 (0.18.1)
idna (2.10)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.7.3)
lxml (3.4.0)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
matplotlib (1.4.2)
mcpi (0.1.1)
nose (1.3.4)
numpy (1.8.2)
oauthlib (3.1.0)
pgzero (1.1)
picamera (1.12)
picraft (0.6)
pifacecommon (4.2.1)
pifacedigitalio (3.1.0)
pigpio (1.30)
Pillow (2.6.1)
pip (1.5.6)
protobuf (3.13.0)
pushbullet.py (0.10.0)
pyasn1 (0.4.8)
pyasn1-modules (0.2.8)
pygame (1.9.2a0)
pygobject (3.14.0)
pyinotify (0.9.4)
pyOpenSSL (0.13.1)
pyparsing (2.0.3)
pyserial (2.6)
python-apt (0.9.3.12)
python-dateutil (2.2)
python-debian (0.1.27)
python-magic (0.4.12)
pytz (2012c)
requests (2.4.3)
requests-oauthlib (1.3.0)
RPi.GPIO (0.6.2)
rsa (4.5)
RTIMULib (7.2.1)
sense-emu (1.0)
sense-hat (2.2.0)
setuptools (5.5.1)
six (1.8.0)
smbus (1.1)
spidev (3.0)
telepot (12.7)
twython (3.1.2)
uritemplate (3.0.1)
urllib3 (1.9.1)
websocket-client (0.40.0)
Werkzeug (0.9.6)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

many thanks for the support.
Matteo

Comment: `urllib3` version `1.9.1` is really old (2014), maybe the method `create_urllib3_context` doesn't exist in this version. Can you upgrade the requirements ?

Comment: I'm trying but i've some trouble; which is the the right comand for the upgrade of the library for python3? thank you

Comment: With pip3 you can do it with `pip3 install --upgrade urllib3`

Comment: I tried but this is the result:
Downloading urllib3-1.25.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127kB): 127kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: urllib3
  Found existing installation: urllib3 1.9.1
    Not uninstalling urllib3 at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, owned by OS
Successfully installed urllib3

Comment: OK, so I guess you don't use a virtual env. You should then follow the procedure to upgrade python on your os